# How to get monospace logic formulas?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, logic

The following does not work in LaTeX because logic symbols can only be used in maths mode:

```
\texttt{\forall x(\exists y((f(x)=y)\land(\neg(g(y)=y))))}
```

I want to do this to stress the nature of such formulas as strings (mathematical objects). The logic symbols should look more similar to the other fixed-width symbols than to normal maths mode symbols. I would then also be able to write the following:

```
If $\phi$ is a formula of first-order logic and $x$ is a variable, then
\texttt{\forall$x$($\phi$)} is again a formula of first-order logic.
```

What's the best way to do this? Obviously, using different commands instead of \forall, \land etc. is fine. Directly entering unicode maths characters would be even better:

```
\texttt{∀x(∃y((f(x)=y)∧(¬(g(y)=y))))}

If $\phi$ is a formula of first-order logic and $x$ is a variable, then
\texttt{∀$x$($\phi$)} is again a formula of first-order logic.
```

I tried XeTeX with \usepackage{utf8x} and it doesn't work. The negation symbol gives "Character172appearedalone", and the other characters are simply not printed.

[Added after first response]

The following is so far the best approximation:

```
\newcommand{\Forall}{$\mathtt\forall$}
\newcommand{\Exists}{$\mathtt\exists$}
\newcommand{\Neg}{$\mathtt\neg$}
\newcommand{\Land}{$\mathtt\land$}
\newcommand{\Lor}{$\mathtt\lor$}

\noindent\texttt{\Forall x\Exists y(x\Land y)}\\
\texttt{abcde\Forall x\Exists y(x\Land y)}
```

The usage example demonstrates that the logic symbols do not have precisely the right width. But it's sufficient for my needs, at least initially. I guess for the final solution I will look up how to make these symbols use width zero and print them over a monotype space character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is no problem with XeTeX *if* you load a font that contains these characters:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}

\texttt{∀x(∃y((f(x)=y)∧(¬(g(y)=y))))}

If $\phi$ is a formula of first-order logic and $x$ is a variable, then
\texttt{∀$x$($\phi$)} is again a formula of first-order logic.

\end{document}
```

Note: Never load the `inputenc` package when compiling with XeTeX.

- Results using DejaVu Sans Mono:
  [image: DejaVu Sans Mono]
- Results using FreeMono:
  [image: FreeMono]

Comment: I tried this on my system (MikTeX 2.8 on Windows XP, numerous special fonts installed): The \land and the \neg come out fine, but the quantifiers are missing in the PDF. I assume this is a font problem?

Comment: @Hans: Yes, you need to make sure that the monospace font selected via `\setmonofont` contains the characters in question. I chose DejaVu Sans Mono for my example because I know it contains them.

Comment: @Philipp: I looked at my type 1 DejaVu Sans Mono font in a font viewer, and it turns out the quantifiers are present in it but _wider_ than the other characters. Very odd. Perhaps that's why they don't appear in the PDF?

Comment: Actually, my font viewer displays the quantifiers in all my fonts, even the most exotic ones, and they tend to not fit into a font's general style. So I guess the font viewer takes them from fall-back fonts without telling me, and they are not actually present in my version of DejaVu Sans Mono. This page confirms that the quantifiers are not present in the font: http://xahlee.org/emacs/emacs_unicode_fonts.html Still looking for one that works, preferably with serifs.

Comment: DejaVu Sans Mono does contain ∀ and ∃, see the [coverage table](http://dejavu.sourceforge.net/samples/DejaVuSansMono.pdf) (page 24) or [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2200/fontsupport.htm). I've added a screenshot of the result.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. It turns out that I had an ancient version of the DejaVu font distribution. Now that I have installed the latest version everything is working as expected. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 5):

can't you use `$\mathtt{\forall x(\exists y((f(x)=y)\land(\neg(g(y)=y))))}$` ?

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about \mathtt. I am not completely happy with this because it's not fixed-width: In particular the parentheses are too narrow and the \land is even spaced as an operator. But I guess I can combine this with \texttt and create special commands for the operators to get the spacing approximately right.